# Change Text of server Control in static Web Method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a web method for ajax call, I want to change the text of my asp.net label control after ajax call.
I am changing its text on success of the ajax call,but after post back I am not getting updated value, as its changing on client side.
I want to change text so  that it  will reflect on post back as well.
How can  I change  the text of label in WebMethod?
Below is my code

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
            public static string RemoveVal()
            {
               //Do some work
    //Return updated Value
//I want to change text here
            }



 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'MyPage.aspx/RemoveVal',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var emaillbl = GetClientID("lblEmail").attr("id");                   
                    $("#" + emaillbl).html(data);

                }

            });

 <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" CssClass="labelclass"></asp:Label>

        function GetClientID(id, context) {
            var el = $("#" + id, context);
            if (el.length < 1)
                el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
            return el;
        }
```

Comment: make a hidden field, In web method put the label text into the HiddenField.Value, use this and assign to the lbl's text property on success of your ajax post back, Try it may be it will work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX call will update control text in client side only. If you want to change label's text after post back , bind the changed value again to the control while page posts back. Like you can call function which binds changed value to label in postback event OR in page load wherever seems fit.